# Error Python API GCP Data Catalog - Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-data-catalog

I'm getting an error trying of use the code of this link: [Data Catalog Example](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/how-to/custom-entries#data-catalog-custom-entry-python). At the step 4, just copy pasting all the code provided, authenticating into my GCP Project and testing it.

Everything is ok until it start creating tag template fields...

```
tag_template = datacatalog_v1.types.TagTemplate()
tag_template.display_name = 'On-premises Tag Template'

tag_template.fields['source'].display_name = 'Source of the data asset'
tag_template.fields['source'].type.primitive_type = \
    datacatalog_v1.FieldType.PrimitiveType.STRING.value
```

it always crash with the same error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHLEC.png)

```
tag_template <proto.marshal.collections.maps.MapComposite object at 0x10fe23310>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ac/Documents/DataCatalog/python_datacatalog/application/sample.py", line 149, in <module>
    tag_template.fields['source'].display_name = 'Source of the data asset'
  File "/Users/ac/Documents/DataCatalog/python_datacatalog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proto/marshal/collections/maps.py", line 56, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'source'
```

Someone can help me sharing alternatives to do this?

Comment: Posting a screenshot of your error makes it difficult for anyone with the same error to find this post.  Please post the text of your error in this question.

Comment: @blindguy thank you for the observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code on the [Data Catalog Example](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/how-to/custom-entries#data-catalog-custom-entry-python) is outdated. Did a few changes on the code starting at step 4 (where you are currently stuck). I encountered another error at the next line for primitive type.

```
# -------------------------------
# 4. Create a Tag Template.
# -------------------------------
tag_template = datacatalog_v1.types.TagTemplate()
tag_template.display_name = 'On-premises Tag Template'

tag_template.fields['source'] = datacatalog_v1.types.TagTemplateField() #creates key 'source'
tag_template.fields['source'].display_name = 'Source of the data asset'
tag_template.fields['source'].type_.primitive_type = datacatalog_v1.types.FieldType.PrimitiveType.STRING #from type -> type_, syntax for primitive type string
```

- Fix is to create the key 'source' for TagTemplateField by adding `tag_template.fields['source'] = datacatalog_v1.types.TagTemplateField()`
- Updated the syntax for ["tag_template.type"](https://googleapis.dev/python/datacatalog/latest/datacatalog_v1/types.html#google.cloud.datacatalog_v1.types.TagTemplateField) and assigning [primitive string value](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.tagTemplates.fields#resource:-tagtemplatefield)

If you proceed to step 5, an error will pop up `KeyError: 'source'`. If you did not encounter this then it is all good. But if ever you encounter it here is the code to fix that.

```
# -------------------------------
# 5. Attach a Tag to the custom Entry.
# -------------------------------
tag = datacatalog_v1.types.Tag()
tag.template = tag_template.name
tag.fields['source'] = datacatalog_v1.types.TagField() #creates key 'source'
tag.fields['source'].string_value = 'On-premises system name'

tag = datacatalog.create_tag(parent=entry.name, tag=tag)
print('Created tag: {}'.format(tag.name))
```

- Fix is similar to step 4 which is to create the key 'source' this time for TagField by adding `tag.fields['source'] = datacatalog_v1.types.TagField() #creates key 'source'`

I ran the whole script from step 1 to 5.

Output of the script:
[image]

Created tag template:
[image]

Created tag:
[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks

And you were right with the Step #5, your solution was in point.